# PHP page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is my main.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    include("connection/config.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>TOM ELOY CONVENIENCE STORE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/iconic.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<!--header link -->
<div id="sitename" class="clear">
    <?php include_once("header.php"); ?>
</div>

<!--menu navigation -->
<div class="wrap">
<nav>
    <?php include_once("menunav.php"); ?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</nav>
</div>



<div id="body-wrapper">
    <!-- body -->
    <div id="body" class="clear">
        <div class="clear">
            <div id="content"></div>
                <!-- script for pages -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js"></script>
                <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>


<!--footer link -->
<div id="footer" align="center">
    <?php include_once("footer.php"); ?>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my javascript the main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#content').load('main2.php');

$('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load( page + '.php');
    return false;
}); 

});
```

this is my supplierprofile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    include("connection/config.php");
?><html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- autorefresh of the table -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Ajax()
    {
        var
            $http,
            $self = arguments.callee;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch(e) {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
        }

        if ($http) {
            $http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                    document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                    setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 0);
                }
            };
            $http.open('GET', 'supplierprofiletable.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
            $http.send(null);
        }

    }
    </script>

</head>

<!-- content2 -->
<div id="content">

        <p id="bcp">Browse Supplier Profile</p><br><br>

                <ul id="nav">        
                    <li>
                        <a id="abutton">PRINT</a>
                        <a id="abutton" href="addspform">ADD SUPPLIER</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


                <!-- autorefresh of the table -->        
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    setTimeout(function() {Ajax();}, 0);
                </script>
                <!-- table to be refresh -->
                <div  id="ReloadThis"><?php include_once("supplierprofiletable.php"); ?></div>          
</div>  

    <? -- script for pages --?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js"></script>
    <script src="js/submain.js"></script>
```

this is the supplieprofiletable.php

```
<table id="spvt" align="center">
<tr>
    <th id="spvth">SUPPLIER NAME</th>
    <th id="spvth">TERMS DAY</th>
    <th id="spvth">VAT</th>
    <th id="spvth">MODIFY</th>
    <th id="spvth">DELETE</th>
</tr>

<?php
    include("connection/config.php");
    $sql = "select * from SUPPLIER_PROFILE ORDER BY SP_NAME";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr id='spvtr'>";
            echo "<td id='spvtd' style='text-align:left;'>" . $row['SP_NAME'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td id='spvtd'>" . $row['SP_TERMS_DAY'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td id='spvtd'>" . $row['SP_VAT'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td id='spvtd'><a href =\"spmodifyform.php?id=" . $row['SP_NO'] . "\">MODIFY SUPPLIER</a></td>";
            echo "<td id='spvtd'><a href =\"spdelete.php?id=" . $row['SP_NO'] . "\">DELETE SUPPLIER</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
?>
```

this is the addspform.php

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="iconic.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type = "text/javascript">
    <!--
    var run1 = function()
    {
        var x1 = document.addsp.spname.value.length;
        if(x1 == 0)
        {
            alert("SUPPLIER NAME SHOULD NOT BE EMPTY");
            return(false);
        }
        else 
            return(true);
    }
    var run2 = function()
    {
        var x1 = document.addsp.spadd.value.length;
        if(x1 == 0)
        {
            alert("SUPPLIER ADDRESS SHOULD NOT BE EMPTY");
            return(false);
        }
        else 
            return(true);
    }
    var run3 = function()
    {
        var x1 = document.addsp.sptd.value.length;
        if(x1 == 0)
        {
          alert("SUPPLIER TERMS DAY SHOULD NOT BE EMPTY");
          return(false);
        }
        else
           return(true);
    }
    var run4 = function()
    {
        var x1 = document.addsp.spvat.value.length;
        if(x1 == 0)
        {
          alert("SUPPLIER VAT SHOULD NOT BE EMPTY");
          return(false);
        }
        else
           return(true);
    }

    function checkall()
    {
        if(run1() == false)
        {
            addsp.spname.focus();
            return(false);
        }
        if(run2() == false)
        {
            addsp.spadd.focus();
            return(false);
        }
        if(run3() == false)
        {
            addsp.sptd.focus();
            return(false);
        }
        if(run4() == false)
        {
            addsp.spvat.focus();
            return(false);
        }
        if(/^[0-9]+$/i.test(addsp.sptd.value) == false)
        {
          alert("invalid Terms Day");
          addsp.sptd.focus();
          return(false);
        }
        else
        {

            return(true);
        }
    }
    -->
</script>

</head>
<!-- body -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="clear">
        <p id="bcp">ADD Supplier</p><br><br>

            <ul id="nav">
                <li>
                    <a id="abutton" href="supplierprofile">VIEW SUPPLIER</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <br>    
                <form id="aft" name ="addsp" action = "addsp.php" method = "post" onsubmit = "return checkall();">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>SUPPLIER FORM (NEW)</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 50px;" >Supplier Name</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <input size="100" type = "text" name = "spname" onkeyup = "this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" value =""/><br />
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 100px;">Address</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <input size="100" type = "text" name = "spadd" value = "" /><br />
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 120px;">Telephone No.</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <input size="100" type = "text" name = "sptelno" value = "" /><br />
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 100px;">Terms Day</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <input size="100" type = "text" name = "sptd" value = "" /><br />
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 100px;">VAT</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <select name="spvat">
                            <option id="o1"> </option>
                            <option id="o2">INCLUSIVE</option>
                            <option id="o3">EXCLUSIVE</option>          
                            </select>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td>
                            <input class="afbutton" type = "submit" name = "ADD" value = "ADD" id="ADD"/>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                    </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>

    </div>  
</div>
    <? -- script for pages --?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js"></script>
    <script src="js/submain.js"></script>
```

this is the addsp.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function direct()
    {
        window.alert("Suppler has been added");
        w = window || document
        w.location.reload();
    }
    -->

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
                include("connection/config.php");
                $spname = $_POST['spname'];
                $spadd = $_POST['spadd'];
                $sptelno = $_POST['sptelno'];
                $sptd = $_POST['sptd'];
                $spvat = $_POST['spvat'];

                if(!$_POST['ADD'])
                {
                  echo "Please fill out the form";
                  header('Location: addspform.php');
                }
                else
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM supplier_profile WHERE sp_name = '$spname'";

                    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                    $counter = 0;
                    while($supplier = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $counter = $counter + 1;
                    }
                    if($counter == 0)
                    {
                      mysql_query("INSERT INTO supplier_profile(`SP_NAME`,`SP_ADDRESS`, `SP_TELNO`,`SP_VAT`,`SP_TERMS_DAY`)
                                   VALUES('$spname','$spadd','$sptelno','$spvat','$sptd')") or die(mysql_error());
                      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                            direct();
                            </script>';
                    }
                }
    ?>
</body>
```

sorry about the previous information. Now if i click the add button to the addspform.php all i want after the javascript that pop-up and click ok is to direct the supplierprofile.php inside  in the main.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your addsp.php like this

```
<?php
                session_start();
                include("connection/config.php");
                $spname = $_POST['spname'];
                $spadd = $_POST['spadd'];
                $sptelno = $_POST['sptelno'];
                $sptd = $_POST['sptd'];
                $spvat = $_POST['spvat'];

                if(!$_POST['ADD'])
                {
                  $_SESSION['msg'] = "Please fill form";
                  header('Location: addspform.php');
                  exit;


                }
                else
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM supplier_profile WHERE sp_name = '$spname'";

                    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                    $counter = 0;
                    while($supplier = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $counter = $counter + 1;
                    }
                    if($counter == 0)
                    {
                      mysql_query("INSERT INTO supplier_profile(`SP_NAME`,`SP_ADDRESS`, `SP_TELNO`,`SP_VAT`,`SP_TERMS_DAY`)
                                   VALUES('$spname','$spadd','$sptelno','$spvat','$sptd')") or die(mysql_error());
                       $_SESSION['msg'] = "form has been submitted successfully";
                       header('Location: addspform.php');
                       exit;
                    }
                }
    ?>
```

you can use header function of php to redirect on some page. use session as msg and print it on your form page as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
     unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>

<form id="aft" name ="addsp" action = "addsp.php" method = "post" onsubmit = "return checkall();">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>SUPPLIER FORM (NEW)</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 50px;" >Supplier Name</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <input size="100" type = "text" name = "spname" onkeyup = "this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" value =""/><br />
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 100px;">Address</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <input size="100" type = "text" name = "spadd" value = "" /><br />
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 120px;">Telephone No.</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <input size="100" type = "text" name = "sptelno" value = "" /><br />
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 100px;">Terms Day</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <input size="100" type = "text" name = "sptd" value = "" /><br />
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                            <span style = "width: 100px;">VAT</span> 
                        </td><td>
                            <select name="spvat">
                            <option id="o1"> </option>
                            <option id="o2">INCLUSIVE</option>
                            <option id="o3">EXCLUSIVE</option>          
                            </select>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td>
                            <input class="afbutton" type = "submit" name = "ADD" value = "ADD" id="ADD"/>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr><td>
                    </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

redefine direct as:

```
    function direct(){
    window.alert("Suppler has been added");
    w = window || document
    w.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: it actually work but it doesn't load the supplierprofile.php to the <div id="content"></div> in the main.php

Comment: you cannot load whole page inside a div unless you create a child iframe tag inside div. create an iframe in "content" div and load supplierprofile.php in that iframe.

Comment: but it works..when i click the button to show the addspform.php. it actually load to the div.

Comment: is there a way that i can reload the <div>

Answer (score 0):

Just do a redirect in `addsp.php`

```
if (test){
       //do something
       echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=yourpage.php">';//This causes the browser to open the new page after 0 seconds, i.e immediately.
    }  else {
       return false;
    }
```

http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
//addsp.php
function direct()
    {
        window.alert("Suppler has been added");
        document.location.href = "main.php?page='pagenamewhichlastloaded'&redirect=1";
    }

//main.php  
$(function(){
    if($("#redirect").val() == 1){
        var page = $("#page").val();
        $('#content').load( page + '.php');
    }
    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load( page + '.php');
        return false;
    });
});

<div id="content"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="page" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['page'])){ echo $_POST['page']; }?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="redirect" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['redirect'])){ echo $_POST['redirect']; }?>" />
```